# Get unique identifier for Angular bootstrap modal to close when user provides response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am working on a project that deals with backend programming in node js and uses sockets to communicate with Angular script .

I have a page where a bootstrap pop up modal opens up when socket event "checkPopUp" is fired. This popup requires user to provide his response by clicking on any of the yes/ No buttons available on modal dialog template.

Now if the socket event is fired twice two modals are opened but both modal close if I give response for the latest opened popup. I want to seperate these modals to close only the modal where user interacted.

I hope I am clear with my question, any help will be appreciated

```
             socket.on('checkPopUp', function(data) {
                $rootScope.all.PopUpObject = {
                    'timestamp': data.fileData[0].trim(),
                    'level': data.fileData[1].trim(),
                    'message_number': data.fileData[2].trim(),
                    'user_name': data.fileData[3].trim(),
                    'buttons': data.fileData[4].trim(),
                    'message': data.fileData[5].trim()
                };


                $rootScope.openMessageModal();

            });

            $rootScope.openMessageModal = function() {
                var modal = $rootScope.modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: './partials/openPopup.html',
                    size: 'sm',
                    scope: $rootScope
                });

            }
```

Comment: Show us some code, and demo a modal opening twice, and we can better help you.

Comment: @FrankerZ I cant show you the working code as it works on the Node js sockets mechanism but i can put the angular code here

Comment: Edited the question with angular code

Comment: You should be able to simulate two modal popups with simple `setTimeout(function() { showmodal() }, 1000);` functions. Try and get one up to jsfiddle, so we can tinker/help you. Right now, I have no way to debug/test this code.